# Twitter Mentions as Comments: There was an error communicating with the Twitter API (error code 403). Please check the plugin settings

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, plugins

I have installed this plugin in my wordpress site "Twitter Mentions as Comments" 
and also created a new app for it through :

```
https://apps.twitter.com/
```

it has generated API key and Secrete Key for me but when i put it in the plugins settings feild it gives me this error

```
Twitter Mentions as Comments: There was an error communicating with the Twitter API (error code 403). Please check the plugin settings.
```

i have searched for it on net but not found any proper solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your application have "read and write" permissions? If not go to https://apps.twitter.com/ and check this permission.

You have to regenerate your tokens and/or api keys after